# Ghostscript error reading a content stream

Tags: ghostscript

I'm try to compact a PDF using Ghostscript however an error appears when executing the command. I'm using ubuntu 18.04, gs version 9.27.

When using debug parameter, show the log below:

```
FAPIhook --nostringval--
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from DAAAAA+LiberationSerif ) is mapped to FAPI=FreeType

FAPIhook --nostringval--
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from DAAAAA+LiberationSerif ) is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
Has GlyphNames2Unicode
(\001) Tj
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
%Resolving: [103 0]
after exec 80 4917888 3330160 2639072 1264388 false 722 7 <0>
Putting.
[612.0 792.0]
```

The problem is that the resulting PDF is not complete.

I'm suspecting that the problem is `GlyphNames2Unicode (\001) Tj`, is there a way to generate the complete PDF even with this error?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your PDF file is broken, exactly how its broken isn't clear, at least in part because you haven't included the full back channel transcript and haven't provided the file to look at.

The errors actually begin with the line:

```
FAPIhook --nostringval--
Font --nostringval-- ( aliased from DAAAAA+LiberationSerif ) is mapped to FAPI=FreeType
```

--nostringval-- isn't legal there, so something is alredy wrong.

The only way to 'generate the complete PDF file' is for Ghostscript to suuccesfully repair the problem. Clearly it isn't doing so currently, which is either a bug or simply a PDF file broken in a new way that the devlopers haven't seen previously. Without seeing the file its not possible to tell.

Probably your best bet is to report this as a bug at bugs.ghostscript.com and attach the PDF file there (along with your command line, which you also haven't given here).

Comment: I executed using `gs -o doc4.ps -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPageList=3 -dPDFSTOPONERROR -dDEBUG documento.pdf` and now return: Has GlyphNames2Unicode
(\001) Tj
Error: /invalidfont in /--.pdfexectoken--
Operand stack:
   --dict:8/16(L)--   --nostringval--   9   (\001)

Comment: So the actual error is an invalid font. Again, I can't tell you whether that's because the font is utterly broken, or whether its a bug, withotu seeing the file, but my guess would be your font is badly corrupted and teh file is broken. Possibly beyond the possibility of recovery, if the font can't be used, then the only solution would be to use a substitute, in which case the output would not be as intended, especially since this is apparently a subset font. The chances of fixing it are low.. You could try not setting -dPDFSTOPONERROR, which will then ignore the error and continue.